# WCF Service client extension

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'd like to wrap adding behavior to wcf client endpoint

The base code is:

```
using (var c = new Service1Client())
{
    c.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new EPBeh());
    c.GetData(1);
}
```

After creating extensions it became a bit different:

```
using (var c = new Service1Client().AddEndpointBehavior<Service1Client, IService1>(new EPBeh()))
{
    c.GetData(1);
}
```

I made it with such extension:

```
public static class ClientExtensions
{
    public static T AddEndpointBehavior<T,C>(this T client, IEndpointBehavior beh) 
        where T : ClientBase<C> 
        where C : class
    {
        client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(beh);
        return client;
    }
}
```

But it looks **awful**

Is there some way to make it chain-like but without explicit defining types of generic?

It should be like

```
var c = new Service1Client().AddEndpointBehavior(new EPBeh());
```

Comment: Does it has to be in code? Or can it be in web.config?

Comment: Yes it should be in code, because logic of building service clients will be quite complex

Comment: `using (var c = new Service1Client())` The auto-generated clients should not be put into a using block, because the `.Dispose()` method will throw if there was an error previously. You will have to do this yourself with a try/finally construct. Microsoft has admitted this is not the preferred behavior but also made clear that they won't change it for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @nvoigt: thanks, ill see some more info about this